# Login post with Bcrypt always return false

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, bcrypt

## Bcrypt.compare returns false no matter what

I'm currently working on a login/register feature in NextJS that utilizes bcrypt to hash and compare user passwords. I'm able to register a user with a hashed password, but when attempting to log in with `bcrypt.compare()`, the comparison always returns false, even when the entered password matches the hashed password.

The issue lies in this line: `const isPasswordMatched = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);`, where the `compare()` method is used to compare the entered password with the hashed password. Despite the method's implementation, it's not working as expected.

[image: Hashed password added on mongodb]

#### `api/auth/[...nextauth].ts`  for login

```js
const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },

  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        await connectDB();
        const { email, password }: Icredential = credentials;

        // Find user by email
        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
        if (user === null) {
          throw new Error('Cannot find user');
        }

        // Check if password from input matches with the one from db
        // This is the line of the concern
        const isPasswordMatched = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
        console.log(`Comparing ${password} to ${user.password}`);
        console.log("match ?", isPasswordMatched);
        // Throw error when it doesn't
        if (!isPasswordMatched)
        // if (password !== '123')
        {
          throw new Error('Invalid email or password');
        }

        // Return authorized user
        return user;
      },
      credentials: undefined
    }),
  ],
};

export default NextAuth(authOptions);
```

#### api/register for register

```js
const registerHandler = async (req: NextApiRequest, res: NextApiResponse) => {
  if (req.method === "POST") {
    try {
      const { user: _regiUser } = req.body;
      console.log(_regiUser)
      //Check if user exists
      await connectDB()
      const existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: _regiUser.email }).exec();
      console.log("existingUser", existingUser);

      //Throw error when email is already in use
      if (existingUser) {
        throw new Error("Email already used");
      }
      //Password encrypted
      const hashedPassword: string = await bcrypt.hashSync( _regiUser.password, 10 );
      console.log("_regiUser.password", _regiUser.password, hashedPassword)
      console.log(hashedPassword)

      //Replace text password with encrypted password
      _regiUser.password = hashedPassword;
      console.log(_regiUser)
      
      //Add user on database
      await User.create(_regiUser)
      res.end()
    } catch (e: any) {
        console.log(e.message)
    }
  }
};

export default registerHandler;
```

Comment: Do you see your `authorize()` function being called when trying to login?

Comment: @WesleyLeMahieu Thanks for your comment, and yes. I can see console.log message from `authorize()` function on terminal very time when i try to login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login logic was completely correct, but I had
wrong User model like following:

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true  //remove this to make it work
  }
});
```

look at password entity, because I copy pasted from email entity, i had a wrong configuration for password. So hash stored in lowercase and this is the very reason why i got error no matter what. smh...

Comment: Yes, that would do it!

Answer (score 0):

You're creating your password hashes using the `hashSync()` method (not async) but trying to run the async `.compare()` method when logging-in. Check out the [examples](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt).

For the comparison, you should be using:

`bcrypt.compareSync(myPlaintextPassword, hash);`

Otherwise, I recommend using the async/await `bcrypt.hash` and `bcrypt.compare` methods. If you want to use `await bcrypto.compare(...)`, create your hash using:

`await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);`

Comment: Even though I changed to async/await for `bcrypt.hash` and `bcrypt.compare`, it is still returning an error. I think I am giving up, although the login/register logic is pretty straightforward to me.